# Trouble with regex capturing group & lazy match

Tags: .net, regex

Using .Net C#, I want to match the names in the $select clause in the follownig :

```
http://serveraddress/ODataServ/WcfDataService.svc/Persons?$select=LAST_NAME_IDNT,FIRST_NAME_IDNT&$top=1&$filter=Id eq '0000'
```

So I would like to have "LAST_NAME_IDNT,FIRST_NAME_IDNT" (i'll split it later based on the comma)

The $select clause can be in the middle of the URL, or at the end, i.e :

```
http://serveraddress/ODataServ/WcfDataService.svc/Persons?$top=1&$filter=Id eq '0000'&$select=LAST_NAME_IDNT,FIRST_NAME_IDNT
```

So I wrote the following pattern : `(\$select\=)(.[^&])*(&|$)`
and tried to get Group 2. I don't know if it's because of lazy matching, but group 2 only contains like two characters : like "NT" in my example.

I don't know how to make it so that I can retrieve "LAST_NAME_IDNT,FIRST_NAME_IDNT"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry the "?" in my initial post was here by accident... I did want to say that I tried this regex (\$select\=)(.[^&])*(&|$) which did not work, and not (\$select\=)(.[^&])*?(&|$) (which also did not work, giving me the same result as the first one)

Comment: Thank you for the two answers and the explanation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex that you are using :

```
(\$select\=)(.[^&])*?(&|$)
```

(.[^&]) - this capturing group captures two characters together. any character and not &.

Now (.[^&])*? means that 0 or more set of these two characters with lazy match. Thus the capturing group will always have the last two characters of the match

Use this instead:

```
(\$select\=)([^&]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your grouping is wrong.. use the following:

```
(\$select\=)([^&]*?)(&|$)        //also no need for '.'
            ↑      ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qT3iQ4/2)